# Sum of residuals of scipy regression model

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics, poisson

I am going through a stats workbook with python, there is a practice hands on question on which i am stuck. Its related to Poisson regression and here is the problem statement:-

Perform the following tasks:

1. Load the R data set Insurance from MASS package and Capture the data as pandas data frame
2. Build a Poisson regression model with a log of an
   independent variable, Holders and dependent variable Claims.
3. Fit the model with data.
4. **Find the sum of residuals**.

I am stuck with point 4 above. Can anyone help with this step?

Here is what i have done so far :-

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Insurance', package='MASS', cache=False).data
poisson_model = smf.poisson('np.log(Holders) ~ -1 + Claims', df)
poisson_result = poisson_model.fit()
print(poisson_result.summary())
```

[image: Here is the output so far :-]

Now how to get sum of residuals?

Comment: Just do: `np.sum(poisson_result.resid)`

Comment: though i got output as 180, it still says that answer is wrong somehow. Trying to figure out how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

np.sum(poisson_result.resid)

works fine

You have used the wrong variables to build the poisson model as pointed out by Karthikeyan.
Use this instead,

poisson_model = smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)',df)

Comment: The below answer is not getting excepted by the FP exercise------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



Optimization terminated successfully.

         Current function value: 3.468160

         Iterations 7

6.679101716144942e-13

Answer (score 2):

**Try below code for Fresco play**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_insurance=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Insurance","MASS")
df_data=df_insurance.data
insurance_model=smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)', df_data).fit()
print(np.cumsum(insurance_model.resid))
```

Comment: Can you explain why cumsum is needed instead of sum ?

Answer (score 1):

1.a) Load the R data set Insurance from MASS package

1.b) and Capture the data as pandas data frame

2) Build a Poisson regression model with a log of an independent variable, Holders and dependent variable Claims.

3) Fit the model with data.

4) Find the sum of residuals.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#load the R data set insurrance from MASS package
ins = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Insurance','MASS').data
# capture the data as pandas data frame
ins_pd = pd.DataFrame(ins)
# build a poisson regressions model with
# a log of an independent variable "Holders" 
# and dependent variable "Claims"
# fit the model with data
result = smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)',data=ins).fit()
# you can also use
# model = smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)',data=ins)
# result = model.fit()

# Find tue sum of residuals
print('Sum ot the residuals:',np.sum(result.resid))
```

i'm new on this so i don't know if capture the data as panda dataframe is fine or not but letme now

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Fresco Mex

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_data=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Insurance","MASS").data
df_dataf= pd.DataFrame(df_data)
insurance_model=smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)',df_data)
insurance_model_result=insurance_model.fit()
print(np.sum(insurance_model_result.resid))
```

Comment: I am getting output like below






Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 3.468160
         Iterations 7
6.679101716144942e-13

Answer (score 0):

in the poisson_model = smf.poisson('np.log(Holders) ~ -1 + Claims', df) statement, the dependent variable "Claims" should come in the right hand side

poisson_model = smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)-1 ', df)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 0):

### this qualified in "Fresco" if anyone is looking for the solution

```
df_insurance=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Insurance","MASS")
df_data=df_insurance.data
insurance_model=smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)',df_data)
insurance_model_result=insurance_model.fit()
res=(insurance_model_result.resid)
print(np.sum(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will work or not .but I  refer this docs

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/doc/MASS/Insurance.html
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

So  I hope this will work too.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import  statsmodels.formula.api as smf 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

data=pd.DataFrame(sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Insurance","MASS",cache=True).data)
model=smf.poisson('Claims ~ District + Group + Age + np.log(Holders)',data).fit()
print(np.sum(model.resid))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `np.cumsum(model.resid)` for this question.

Ideally `np.sum(model.resid)` should be the right answer for the question... But if the system is not accepting it, try the `cumsum`